# Update metadata w/2013 REST API in a Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, rest, metadata, api

I am looking for an example of a REST PUT/MERGE method done from a workflow (no code) in SharePoint Designer to update a metadata field in a library. Specifically what the Build Dictionary and Call would look like.

Thank you for the help!